# Создать запрос с добавлением столбца совпадений с другой таблицей по столбцу через regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Добрый день!
Есть две таблицы param_card_value product_card

```
param_card_value        product_card                       
id  | value             id | param_value_ids
232 | val1              1  | ;232;233;
233 | val1              2  | ;234;
234 | val1              3  | ;232;234;
```

Можно ли создать запрос который возвращал количество совпадений param_card_value.id в product_card.param_ids через regexp для каждой строки таблицы param_card_value

Т.е. я делаю Select * param_card_value а далее join добавляет столбец совпадений

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался

```
SELECT p.* , 
(SELECT count(*) 
     FROM `product_card`as u 
     WHERE u.param_value_ids REGEXP p.id
) as c
FROM  `param_card_value` AS p,  `product_card` AS u
WHERE p.name_id =24 and p.deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: `u.param_value_ids REGEXP p.id` Если все `p.id` строго трёхсимвольные - ещё более-менее... иначе получишь хрень...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pc.id, SUM(pc.param_value_ids LIKE CONCAT('%;',pcv.id,';%')))
FROM param_card_value pcv, product_card pc
GROUP BY pc.id
```

Если очень хочется - перепиши на REGEXP...